# I have a pool of 10 practice exams, which 2 of these will appear on the exam, and I want to see at least one of the ones I completed, on exam day.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-theorem, pigeonhole-principle

How many exams do I need to complete if I have a pool of 10 practice exams to choose from, which 2 of these will appear on the exam, and I want to see at least one of the ones I completed, on exam day.

I know the answer is 9 applying the pigeonhole principle, but cannot show it is.

The number of possible combinations is $\binom{10}2$ for how many different possibilities could be presented on exam day.

I am thinking that the worst case is that if you study 8, there is 1 option where you could be given those two on the exam, hence the answer is 9.

I am hoping to see if someone can help approach this mathematically to show the answer is indeed 9 (either through Binomial or some sort of cdf function?)

Thank you

Comment: Seeing at least one what? This is a very badly formulated question. $\binom {10}2$ counts the number of combinations of what?

Comment: I believe your analysis is correct. For the worst case scenario, if you study $8$, but the unsolved $2$ can appear in the exam, in which you have not completed both. Hence you need at least 9.

Comment: Thank you - great to know it is 9 as well. Would you happen to know how to show this mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

Of 10 practice exam papers, if 2 of them will appear in the real exam, then if you practice 9 of them. 1 paper in the real exam can be the 1 you *didn't practice* but the other paper *has to be* from the 9 you practiced.

If you practice $n$ papers, the probability that the $2$ that appear in the real exam is not among these $n$ = $\frac{^{10 - n}C_2}{^{10}C_2}$

The probability that the 2 questions will be from the $n$ you did practice = $P(E) = 1 - \frac{^{10 - n}C_2}{^{10}C_2}$

With 8 questions $P(E) = 1 - \frac{^2C_2}{^{10}C_2} = \frac{44}{45}$

With 9 questions, $P(E) = 1 - \frac{^1C_2}{45}$

$^1C_2 = 0$???

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant to the question. OP isn't asking for the probability of the event occurring if 2 tests are done. OP wants the event to occur, and is asking for how many tests need to be done.

Comment: Yes, any insight to how we could arrive at the answer "9 trials" would be great please.

Comment: @Mathsider, I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you - that is a good approach!

Comment: Just wondering if there is a way to show this using deductive reasoning, rather than having that value and "trialing" values?

Comment: @Mathsider, edited answer.

Comment: Could you share how you got P(E) is 2/10 please?
Since the trials are dependent, I calculated 1- (44/45) (as you did before)

Comment: @Mathsider, I edited my answer